# Why shouldn't I put user input in HTML comments?

Tags: xss, html

The [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) has a list of locations where untrusted data should never be put:

> ```
>  <script>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</script>   directly in a script
>
>  <!--...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...-->             inside an HTML comment
>
>  <div ...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...=test />       in an attribute name
>
>  <NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE... href="/test" />   in a tag name
>
>  <style>...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...</style>   directly in CSS
> ```

I understand why data shouldn't be put into the other 4 places, but what is the danger of putting user input into HTML comments? I would think that encoding `>` would be enough to prevent any attacks. Is there a way to execute JavaScript inside a HTML comment? Or a different way to exit HTML comments without `>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The relevant entries in the [HTML5 Security Cheatsheet](https://html5sec.org/) are:

- Ending HTML comments with a backtick character: [html5sec#133](https://html5sec.org/#133) (IE6, IE8)
- Injecting XSS or with a conditional comment [html5sec#115](https://html5sec.org/#115) (older IE, IE quirks mode)

Apart from that user input might be used to change this comment into a conditional comment (IE only) and thus change the DOM or block the execution of script after the comment. This could change the behavior of the page in an unintended way.

Comment: Another surprising thing: the ``--`` part starts and ends a SGLM comment, which is inside an empty HTML tag. Older browsers had problem with ``<script><!-- some_code;decrement_this--;some_other_code --></script>``, because the decrement operator ended the SGML comment.

Comment: @allo Note that since it applies to only very old browsers (probably only IE before IE6), then I would not consider it as an issue. But [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments) give a lot of restrictions about starting/ending a comment. Even if a lot of these involve a `<` or `>` character (which should be properly encoded by any HTML encoding function), it's worth checking.

Answer (score 3):

If untrusted data can be everything, we could inject for example `--><script>alert("I just escaped the HTML comment")</script><!--`
which would make it appear in source code like: `<!----><script>alert("I just escaped the HTML comment")</script><!---->`(Note the empty comments)

Comment: True, but if I can inject `-->`, I'm not in a comment context anymore, but in a HTML element context. In that case, OWASP `RULE #1` would apply, which says untrusted data may be printed if escaped.

Comment: Exactly. Escaping the context is why it's written to OWASP as security vulnerability, as some people may not understand the mechanics of XSS overall, and they could think "Oh, so if I let users edit HTML comments, nothing bad can happend right?"