# Is this XSS filter for HTML comments safe?

Tags: web-application, xss, html

HTML comments can be notoriously tricky from an XSS standpoint, and the standard recommendation seems to be to [never put untrusted user data in them](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126721/why-shouldnt-i-put-user-input-in-html-comments). But shouldn't it be possible to strip out a few characters and make it safe?

My theory is that the following should be enough:

- `>` for closing the comment.
- `[` for [conditional comments](https://html5sec.org/#115).
- `` ` `` for [strange IE issue](https://html5sec.org/#133)
- `<` and `]` for symmetry.

If I strip them out, am I safe? Implemented in PHP you get:

```
function echo_html_comment($content) {
    // Warning! This code is untested and therefore unsafe. Do not use!
    $content = str_replace(['<', '>', '[', ']', '`'], '', $content);
    echo "<!-- $content -->";
}
```

I consider character encoding exploits outside the scope of the question. You can also assume that comments will only be put between HTML tags, not inside attributes or in other strange places.

You could easily make the argument that the risk is not worth it for something as pointless as a HTML comment, and I might agree. But what I am interested in here is if the above filter is actually breakable?

Comment: in my opinion you should replace even the equal sign an the parentheis . tw if the user can manipulate an input in a script block a '-alert()-' is enogh.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to unpack here, and so I will do my best you give you a fair and accurate response while keeping this relatively brief. Firstly, I don't think that your `echo_html_comment()` XSS sanitizer is effective but, rather, I think that you have defined it in such a way as to have an effective sanitizer. When you say that "I consider character encoding exploits outside the scope of the question", I think you are misunderstanding how XSS prevention works (no offense meant!). If you narrowly consider dumping user input into `<!-- -->` without any further context and stipulating oddly specific prohibitions (such as no character encodings, etc) then your XSS sanitizer *seems* legit. However, you gotta ask yourself not just *what* can happen directly when their input is put into a comment but also *where* is it being put in the DOM and *how* is it being dynamically interacted with (if at all). These are incredibly relevant questions that are broader than just analyzing if the attacker can insert XSS that will immediately execute. Let me try to explain with an example. Imagine that a developer codes in a div tag that puts uses your `echo_html_comment()` PHP function to dump the user's content into a comment in that div:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <span>Content 1</span>
    <span>Content 2</span>
    <?= echo_html_comment($userInput) ?>
</div>
```

Now, if we just look at the situation within this narrow scope (of what I've told you so far), it seems as though nothing bad can happen as the attacker has no viable means of breaking out of the html comment tag (as we are stipulating that the comment isn't placed in weird places, etc). However, let's ask ourselves *how is the developer interacting with that div?*: now we need to zoom out and analyze a broader scope. For example, let's say this is the code:

```
<div id="firstDiv">
    <span>Content 1</span>
    <span>Content 2</span>
    <?= echo_html_comment($userInput) ?>
</div>

<div id="secondDiv">

</div>

<script>
    const nodes = document.getElementById('firstDiv').childNodes;

    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('secondDiv').innerHTML += nodes[i].textContent;
    }

    document.getElementById('firstDiv').innerHTML = document.getElementById('secondDiv').innerText;
</script>
```

Now we have XSS! Why? Because the developer is manipulating that div, which encompasses the HTML comment they sanitized, in a way that introduces XSS--regardless of whether the developer realizes it or not (in this case, it is piss poor JS code). For example, if the `$userInput` were to be `&lt;audio src=x onerror=alert(1)&gt;`, then the XSS payload will execute just fine. I think this is the more fundamental thing that I think you are misunderstanding: it is misleading to assume that your `echo_html_comment()` function is actually *safe* where a developer were to be able to trust that they can put it anywhere that they normally would (aka, nested within an element) because XSS prevention is about determining not only *what* an attacker can influence directly but also *how* and *where* the developer is using it. I will admit that my example is a bit technical, but my point is that when someone says their sanitizer is XSS *safe* within a context, it should be safe no matter the *how* or the *where* (*where* within context, so I wouldn't hold it against you that they could execute XSS directly with quotation marks in an input value because the context you provided was that the HTML comment was used in between elements--which is how they are normally used). This leads me to my second point: **always whitelist**. Never, ever, ever, blacklist. As you kind of alluded to at the end of your post: is it really worth it? If someone uses your `echo_html_comment`, they are not guarenteed anything so long as you are blacklisting: attackers come up with incredibly complex and specifically tailored to the situation exploits (which includes char encoding). Attackers don't just look at what they can do directly (or immediately): they may plan a perfect exploit that doesn't actually trigger their XSS payload until their user input has gone down and completely through allison's rabbit hole. The rule of thumb is always only allow what you want them to be able to input. Then not only do you not have to try to think of all the evolving and incredibly complicated ways people come up with XSS but you also know exactly what to expect from them--which gives you the upper hand (advantage).